# PrestaShop stock in mysql table

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Just a quick question

In which table in database can i find the available stock (not using advanced stock) in PrestaShop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Available quantities should be stored in [prefix]_stock_available

Comment: I don't have that table .. PrestaShop 1.6

Comment: That's strange, it's part of ps core. Are you shure that your shop is correctly installed? Try to install a new instance of prestashop and look at the db if the table is there.

Comment: @DesterDezzods did you look at `ps_stock_available` table? Maybe you should give us your `DB Prefix` or one of table names.

Comment: @HddnTHA, Mir Oops my mistake. Phpmyadmin didnt show that table in tables list. Now its okey after i did select from